# CalendarIdentifier in UWP CalendarDatePicker

Tags: datepicker, uwp

I have used CalendarDatePicker with `CalendarIdentifier="PersianCalendar"` in my UWP app:

```
<CalendarDatePicker x:Name="btnDatePicker" CalendarIdentifier="PersianCalendar" PlaceholderText="..." IsTodayHighlighted="False"></CalendarDatePicker>
```

Everything works fine until the user selects a Persian date and then `CalendarDatePicker` displays the Gregorian date.

Any help or insight is much appreciated.

Comment: This probably is the default behavior of CalendarDatePicker. There's a very nice Culture aware Month calendar and DatePicker on codeproject, perhaps this can be trimmed to use in UWP http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45684/Culture-Aware-Month-Calendar-and-Datepicker

Answer (score 1):

As you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.calendaridentifiers?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), there is "Persian" calendar available, however I did not find any way to set CalendarIdentifier to Persian in Xaml, but it's possible to set it in Code Behind:

```
btnDatePicker.CalendarIdentifier = CalendarIdentifiers.Persian;
```

and everything should work fine:

[image]